# Access to HttpServletResponse cookies

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cookies

I'm trying to migrate from tomcat 6 to tomcat 8.
I have to get access to *org.apache.catalina.connector.Response*  cookies.

In tomcat 6 there were a method to do that 
[getCookies()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Response.html#getCookies())

This method is deprecated in Tomcat 8. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hi Kradas. Please explain more about what you're trying to achieve. First thing on my mind was a ServletFilter in which you pass along an own implementation of HttpServletResponseWrapper that overrides the addCookie() methods and stores cookies in a field you can later retrieve them from...

Comment: Well, I have an org.apache.catalina.connector.Response object. This object contains a cookie arraylist that i need to achive. And I dont know how to it in tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CookieStoringFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {     
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(res instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            chain.doFilter(req, new CookieStoringResponse((HttpServletResponse)res));
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {     
    }

}
```

It will wrap the response into something called CookieStoringResponse:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class CookieStoringResponse extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    protected List<Cookie> cookies;

    public CookieStoringResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);        
    }

    public void addCookie(Cookie c) {
        cookies.add(c);
        super.addCookie(c);
    }

    public List<Cookie> getCookies() {
        return cookies;
    }
}
```

Once you've installed this filter (in web.xml)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>CookieStoringFilter</filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

you can then check the response if it is of the cookie counting type and then retrieve list of cookies added:

```
public void doGet(HttpServetRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    if(res instanceof CookieStoringResponse)) {
        System.out.println("I have " + ((CookieStoringResponse)res).getCookies().size() + " cookies stored");
    }
}
```

Remeber that Cookies can be set via Header-Values as well - so this might be only a starting point.