# Why Cookie name and value is 'http' and 'proxy' respectively without having created one in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, cookies

I am trying to create a simple cookie program in servlet using eclipse.

This is how it is:-

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();


    if(cookies == null)
    {
        out.print("<b> Hello Stranger </b><br>");

    }
    else
    {
        for(Cookie cookie:cookies)
        {
            out.print("<b> Hello" + cookie.getValue() + "</b>");
        }
    }

    out.print("<form action = '' method = 'post'>");
    out.print("What is your name?");
    out.print("<input type = 'text' name = 'username'><br>");
    out.print("<br>");
    out.print("<input type = 'submit'>");
    out.print("</form>");


}

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String str = request.getParameter("username");

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

    if (cookies == null)
    {
        Cookie c  = new Cookie("username",str);
        c.setMaxAge(-1);
        response.addCookie(c);
    }

    for(Cookie cookie: cookies)
    {
        out.print("<b> Hello," + cookie.getName() + "</b>");
    }
}
```

When running it in the tomcat server using eclipse
instead of getting output as **Hello Stranger** I am getting **Hello http**
Even after clicking on submit
It is showing the same thing instead of the name entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're iterating through (and printing) the list of cookies contained in the inbound HttpServletRequest, but you're adding the new cookie to the HttpServletResponse.

While the [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) has an addCookie() method, it doesn't have a matching getCookies(), so you would need to work around this if your wish to see the cookies you have added to the response object.  There are several posts that cover this, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507477/is-there-any-way-to-read-cookies-from-the-response-object-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735643/access-to-httpservletresponse-cookies).

Comment: But it seems to work now! isn't Cookie supposed to be one thing. I mean after adding the cookie in the response object, the response(containing the cookie) is sent to the client and get stored there. Now each further request from the client side should contain all the cookies set for that particular webpage.

i.e when I hit the refresh page the doGet method is called but now Cookie is already present!

Comment: Yup - subsequent requests to the same servlet from the client will contain cookies set in earlier responses.